# spring boot 2 actuator jvm.gc.memory.allocated Metric

Tags: spring-boot, memory-management, garbage-collection, spring-boot-actuator, openjdk-11

i'm using spring boot 2.2.5 and monitoring my application metrics via spring boot actuator and Grafana.

my application is packaged with Docker(OpenJdk11) and configured with 4GB of memory

i'm having long gc pauses that get around 1-2 seconds, and it is correlated with high **jvm.gc.memory.allocated** .

the jvm.gc.memory.allocated metrics sometimes gets to **30GB**

can anyone explain the **jvm.gc.memory.allocated** metric ? what does it mean ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather weird metric, if you ask me (in the sense that it is not trivial to grasp). Let's take it slow.

First of all it is generated by `micrometer` [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmGcMetrics.java#L116) and if you read it's description:

> Incremented for an increase in the size of the young generation memory pool after one GC to before the next

it probably would make little sense to you too. I had to look at what the code that computes it, to understand what it does.

If you know some basic things about how a GC works and [look at this code](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmGcMetrics.java#L177), things are rather simple, actually.

A *generational* garbage collector (like `G1`) divides the heap into *regions* (`young` and `old`). Allocations of new Objects happen in the young region (unless `humongous`, but I will not get into it), specifically in `Eden space`. Once a GC is triggered, `Eden` is cleared and allocations can happen again. This is rather simplified and not *entirely* correct (things are slightly different in case of `major/mixed` collections).

Now that this theory is in place, you can look at what `isYoungGenPool` is, from :

```
if (youngGenPoolName != null) {
      final long youngBefore = before.get(youngGenPoolName).getUsed();
      final long youngAfter = after.get(youngGenPoolName).getUsed();
      final long delta = youngBefore - youngGenSizeAfter.get();
      youngGenSizeAfter.set(youngAfter);
      if (delta > 0L) {
           allocatedBytes.increment(delta);
      }
}
```

Specifically, it is defined [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmMemory.java#L45):

> ... endsWith("Eden Space")

As such, this code takes a snapshot - of what `Used Space` was *before* and *after* a GC cycle in the `Eden Space`, computes a `delta` and adds all these deltas into a single value. This is what `jvm.gc.memory.allocated` is.

---

This sort of measures how much your application allocates during its lifetime, but only via *young* space. imho, you should carefully look at it since :

- it does not track humongous allocations (there is a different metric for this)
- it only works for generational garbage collectors (`Shenandoah` is not such a collector for example)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!
does this metric show how many bytes were allocated between each GC cycle ?
and if the metric is calculated before the GC and after the GC, does it mean how many bytes were cleared our of Eden space in one GC cycle   ?

what i'm still missing from your answer, why this metric is so high in relative to my heap size ?(4GB heap)

Comment: @EliaRohana that is a _counter_, I mean look at the code - it just keeps _adding_ those bytes.